# Best practice for filtering MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, join, filter

I want to implement a filter-function in my PHP project.
To implement a filter, I usually just add a WHERE clause in my query to show filtered results.

My Problem is:
These filters require not only a smple added WHERE clause, but a **huge** Query including multiple JOINs. The resulting Query has > 30 lines.

Later, there should also be a search function which would then also require this huge query.
I wonder if this is a good practice or if I should add a "redundant" Database column to my database table where I compute the attribute I need for filtering on every update.
With this column, I wouldnt have my huge query on different places over my project, but have a redundant column.

What do you think?

Greetings

**As questioned, here the table structure/code.** This is not the exact code, because there is also a revision system which makes it even more complex, but for understanding this is enough:

**table submissions:**

```
ID (primary)
(additionalColumns)
```

**table reports:**

```
ID (primary)
submissionID (reference to submission table)
(additionalColumns)
```

**table report_objects:**

```
reportID (reference to reports table, multiple report_object for one report)
```

**table accounting:**

```
ID (primary)
reportID (reference to reports table, multiple accountings for one report)
(additionalColumns)
```

**table accounting_objects:**

```
ID
accountingID (reference to accounting table, multiple accounting_object for one accounting)
(additionalColumns)
```

For a submission, one or multiple reports are being create with multiple objects to account (report_objects).
For each report, I can create multiple accountings, where each accounting is for a few objects of the report. The accounted report_objects are stored in accounting_object

My query/filter checks, if each report_object of a submissionID is accounted (accounting_object exists) for one submissionID.

Comment: How about using a view or (even) materialized view?

Comment: If we can see the SQL statement and / or schema we can have a shot at helping you out. @YohanesGultom +1 for materialized view... Normally the answer to this sort of problem.

Comment: @StuartWakefield: The question is tagged [tag:mysql], which [does not currently support materialized views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/faqs-views.html#qandaitem-B-6-1-5).

Comment: @eggyal out of the box I agree, although you can still implement materialized views in practice though.

Comment: I added my table structure in the above post. Hope this helps // EDIT: updated the structure, little mistake in accounting_objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one definitive answer and, in practice, if it works and runs quickly enough for your needs then you can leave it as is. Optimization is always something you can come back to.

### Joining correctly

If you are simply checking for the existence of a join table and only including the results with that join you can do this through the correct LEFT / RIGHT JOIN expressions. This is always the first call.

### Expressiveness

Also be as expressive as you can with SQL, you want to give it the best chance to optimize your query, there are keywords such as EXISTS, for example, make sure to use them.

### Denormalization

You can add in a column that stores the computed value, the complexity that arises out of this is ensuring that the value is always up to date. This can be done by triggers or manually. The pros:

- It is the easiest method of getting around slowness introduced by computed columns.

The cons:

- Ruins your nice normalized schema
- If you do it manually in code, you will forget to do it somewhere, causing headaches.
- Triggers can be a bit of a pain.

### Materialized view

This is like denormalization but prevents polluting your normalized tables by created a stored view. This is achieved in MySQL by storing the result of your complex select into a results table when the values change. Again, the same as denormalization, the complexity is keeping this up to date. It is typically done with triggers. This can be a pain but keeps the complexity out of your schema. As mentioned by@eggyal it isn't a supported feature of MySQL yet so you will have to DIY...
[Materialized views with MySQL](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views)

Pros:

- Keeps dirty denormalized stuff away from your nice normalized schema.

Cons:

- Materialized views aren't supported so setting them up requires work.
- If you trigger the refresh of your views in code you get stale data, but isn't quite as painful as the single column staleness of denormalization.
- Triggers can be a bit of a pain.

If you aren't sure, and it really matters, do some benchmarking.

**EDIT** If you code has this query in one form or another across your code base then that has the possibility of cause headaches in future as you will have to remember to change the statements in all of the places if or when they change.

If by doing the above you have made your statements really simple and concise then they may differ enough from each other for it to not be a problem.

You can do some things to help you out:

1. Put all of the related queries in a single place, i.e. a single class or script that handles this query in its various forms. This way at least all of the changes are limited to the one file.
2. You can, to help yourself out a bit more, do a bit of refactoring it to remove duplication between the queries.

Also, If you feel the database information is too exposed to the code you may want to abstract it behind a view.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! At the moment, the performance does not really matter, there won't be so much users using this system at the same time. I am just wondering what is a good practice here. If I leave the query as it is, if would be in 3-4 places over my project in a slightly customized way (count filtered objects for paging, query filtered objects, advanced search with filtering, ...). This means that I have to make sure all queries are updated if I make any changes. As is said and as you can see in my first post, the table structure is rather complex, so maintaining is not that easy.

Comment: Thanks for adding pro and cons. Denormalization is the keyword I was looking for. I think I will go to denormalizing the stuff. In my case this will be less painfull than maintaining the ugly queries elsewhere (:

Comment: No problems, we can't all be puritans ;)

Comment: The pro of denormalization in my case is, that I already have a central class where I can make sure thath on each update() call where for example the accounting is being updated, I can compute my filter attribute and update the denormalized field.

Comment: That sounds like a sensible route